# When clicking on draggable element, it is being 'stick' on cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on my draggable element, the cursor gets that element and like "stick to it". The element only "unattach" from cursor when I make a click with a mouse move.

Looking at the draggable documentation from jQuery UI, it doesn't have this behavior.

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#default

This is my code:

```
$(".drag").draggable({
 cursor: "move",
 revert: true,
});
```

Does anyone have any idea of what it might be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which version of jqueryui are you using and is your browser Internet Explorer?

Comment: Hi @ErcanPeker ! The version of jQuery UI is 1.12.1 and I'm testing in Chrome.

Comment: Can you make an example in jsfiddle?